# Running route handlers multiple times - ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express

How can I make an array of route handlers execute recursively? This is my below code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/routePath/:times", [handler1,handler2,handler3]);

handler1 = (req,res,next)=>{
//Some Folder decompressing operation
next();
}

handler2 = (req,res,next)=>{
//Some business logic
next();
}

handler3 = (req,res)=>{
//Some file operation
}
```

One way I found out was to chain the functions via promises and then call the functions inside a single route handler containing a for loop.
But is there any other work around/npm module that can be done/used on the above code to run the array of handlers recursively?

Comment: As you are using express you can achieve this via middleware

Comment: No. If I change the handlers to separate middlewares, then i cannot run those middlewares recursively. To run them recursively, I need to keep sending new request each time.